# How to leave space at the top when iframe goes fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

When iframe(from different domain) goes fullscreen I want to leave some space at the top for website navigation. Is it possible to set top margin?

```
    <iframe id="iframe" src="...." allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: You cannot be fullscreen with a margin, however, you can set the width and height to 100% with CSS inside a container that leaves space for your navigation.

Comment: Did you mean `iframe{margin-top:100px;}`?

Comment: I've tried to solve it with CSS. But it doesn't work. I guess it should be done with javascript and screen.height. Just don't know how to implement it.